# Replace A Column Value by Most Frequent Value In Group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'student': list('AAABBBCCCC'),
                   'city': ['LA', 'LA', 'NY', 'DC', 'NY', 'NY', 'SF', 'SF', 'LA', 'SF'],
                   'score': [75, 27, 31, 22, 43, 20, 26, 40, 33, 20]})

print(df)

  student city  score
0       A   LA     75
1       A   LA     27
2       A   NY     31
3       B   DC     22
4       B   NY     43
5       B   NY     20
6       C   SF     26
7       C   SF     40
8       C   LA     33
9       C   SF     20
```

I have to replace the `city` column based on which city appears most for that student. For example, here is the `value_counts()` of the city for each student:

```
df.groupby('student').city.value_counts()

student  city
A        LA      2
         NY      1
B        NY      2
         DC      1
C        SF      3
         LA      1
```

We can see, for the student `A`, `LA` appears most of the time. Hence, we want to replace other cities (here `NY`) with `LA`.

**Desired output**:

```
  student city  score
0       A   LA     75
1       A   LA     27
2       A   LA     31
3       B   NY     22
4       B   NY     43
5       B   NY     20
6       C   SF     26
7       C   SF     40
8       C   SF     33
9       C   SF     20
```

What would be the ideal way of getting the desired output? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the most frequent value with `mode`, which is a bit faster than `value_counts`. Then you can use `groupby().transform()` to broadcast the values to all the rows:

```
# lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0] would also work
df['city'] = df.groupby('student')['city'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
  student city  score
0       A   LA     75
1       A   LA     27
2       A   LA     31
3       B   NY     22
4       B   NY     43
5       B   NY     20
6       C   SF     26
7       C   SF     40
8       C   SF     33
9       C   SF     20
```

**Note** `mode()` doesn't count `NaN` values, so if a student is missing `city` on all rows, `mode()` would throw an error.